# Finding expected no of heads in tossing of $n$ unbiased coins

Tags: probability-distributions

Expected number of heads when we toss $n$ unbiased coins is

1. $2n$
2. $n$
3. $\frac{n}{2}$
4. $\frac{n}{4}$.

When I tried , I got $\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}.$

Comment: It wouldn't have been too much effort to write out the problem as stated would it? If $n=10$ your formula gives $1023/1024$. Do you really believe that the expected number of heads when you toss 10 coins is just under 1?

Comment: *Hint:* Since the coin is unbiassed, the expected count of *heads* equals the expected count of *tails*, and the count of both certainly equals $n$.

Answer (score 1):

If the coin is unbiased, in every flip, it is equally likely to be head or tail.

Hence, the answer is $\frac{n}{2}$.

Remark: also note that the number of heads follow binomial distribution.

Would you like to share with us how did you get your answer and perhaps we can point out your flaw in your thought.

Comment: Really appreciate that, thank you. But, finding the expected no of heads, doesn't it mean calculating mean of no of heads using the formula for mean i.e. sigma Variable X times P(X)?

Comment: Yes, the formula $\sum_{x=0}^n  xP(x)$ is correct, would you like to show us your $P(x)$?  Remark: In this case, we can just regconize that it is binomial distributed or use the property that sum of expectation is the expectation of sum.